# DataTables - translate a text which relates to select extension

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm using jQuery DataTables v1.10.9 with Select extension.

When selecting a row or more, there is a text that appears in the bottom, for example, 
*"2 rows selected"*, see the screenshot below:

[image]

Language File:

```
{
    "sEmptyTable":     "No data available in table",
    "sInfo":           "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ entries",
    "sInfoEmpty":      "Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries",
    "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtered from _MAX_ total entries)",
    "sInfoPostFix":    "",
    "sInfoThousands":  ",",
    "sLengthMenu":     "Show _MENU_ entries",
    "sLoadingRecords": "Loading...",
    "sProcessing":     "Processing...",
    "sSearch":         "Search:",
    "sZeroRecords":    "No matching records found",
    "oPaginate": {
        "sFirst":    "First",
        "sLast":     "Last",
        "sNext":     "Next",
        "sPrevious": "Previous"
    },
    "select": {
        "rows": {
            "_": "You have selected %d rows",
            "0": "Click a row to select",
            "1": "1 row selected"
        }
    }
}
```

**Table initialization:**

```
dataTableY = $('#tableID').DataTable({
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
        url: myProp.base_url + 'directory/class/method'
    },
    processing: true,
    scrollY: 420,
    paging: true,
    info: true,
    searchable: true,
    select: {
        style: 'os'
    },
    pagingType: 'full_numbers',
    language: {
        url: myProp.base_url + '/DataTables/lang/language.json'
    }
});
```

How can I translate this text ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        select: true,
        language: {
            select: {
                rows: {
                    _: "You have selected %d rows",
                    0: "Click a row to select it",
                    1: "Only 1 row selected"
                }
            }
        }
    } );
} );
```

See [Select - Internationalization example](http://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/initialisation/i18n.html) for demonstration.

If you would like to use it in the language file, use the format below:

```
{
    "sEmptyTable":     "No data available in table",
    "sInfo":           "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ entries",
    "sInfoEmpty":      "Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries",
    "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtered from _MAX_ total entries)",
    "sInfoPostFix":    "",
    "sInfoThousands":  ",",
    "sLengthMenu":     "Show _MENU_ entries",
    "sLoadingRecords": "Loading...",
    "sProcessing":     "Processing...",
    "sSearch":         "Search:",
    "sZeroRecords":    "No matching records found",
    "oPaginate": {
        "sFirst":    "First",
        "sLast":     "Last",
        "sNext":     "Next",
        "sPrevious": "Previous"
    },
    "select": {
        "rows": {
            "_": "You have selected %d rows",
            "0": "Click a row to select",
            "1": "1 row selected"
        }
    }
}
```

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/scw8dp55/2/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Thank you, it is working only when add it to `language{}` directly like your example , but when add it to json language file it does not work.

Comment: @LionKing, see [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/scw8dp55/), it also works with the language file.

Comment: @LionKing, info control is still wrong `1 to 50 of 1208 entries (filtered from 50 total entries)`, looks like you have `recordsTotal` and `recordsFiltered` swapped again.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately still not work. about your note I'm have applied this php code : `$recordsTotal = $dbData->num_rows(); $recordsFiltered = $this->ajax_model->countAll_memebers(); $data = array();`

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately still does not want to translate. I don't know what the problem, the translation file like your file.

Comment: @LionKing, these characters `_`, `1`, `2` should be quoted.

Comment: I have already did it exactly like your example, but  unfortunately still does not translate. ok, if not, can I hide this part only from info bar.

Comment: @LionKing, it works in my example, you must be doing something wrong. Are you using the most recent DataTables and select extension? Do you see other elements translated with your language file?

Comment: This is my translation [json file](http://www.mediafire.com/view/h93rw0inxp308b7/Arabic.json) . you can check .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92651/discussion-between-lion-king-and-gyrocode-com).

Comment: Then, the problem maybe in my table initialization. I have been updated my question.

Comment: @LionKing, put this URL `'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1jkao'` instead of your language file URL and see if that works. Your initializaiton options seems to be OK.

Comment: Thank you so much for your continued help me. now work fine without doing anything, maybe the problem was in the browser cache.
What about  `recordsTotal` and `recordsFiltered` that you mentioned me previously. if you don't mind to chat with me about this point.